# EMR-4.2.0 Error during running of custom jar (command-runner)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am running sqoop installation script in AWS - EMR-4.2.0 Version, followed [this documentation](http://rohitghatol.com/?p=699).
After created cluster (at Steps), I have submitted my sqoop script as an arguments and s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar/ command-runner.jar as a jar file, but getting error like this. Can you help me pls what is the cause and problem?
[image: emr jar]

Error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://bmsgcm/spark/install-sqoop.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.CommandRunner.main(CommandRunner.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://bmsgcm/spark/install-sqoop.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:92)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1):

command-runner.jar can only read local files. You can add a bootstrap script to copy files from S3 to local file system.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybox is correct. Unlike `script-runner.jar` that was used on the 2.x and 3.x EMR AMIs, `command-runner.jar` can only run local commands. A bootstrap script is the best way to do this.

For instance, if you have a few spark drivers on S3, and you have a shell script (also on S3) to copy them to the master node for later use in a job flow step with `spark-submit`, then you might have had a step like this:

```
Steps=[
    {
        'Name': 'Install My Spark Drivers',
        'ActionOnFailure':'TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW',
        'HadoopJarStep':
            'Jar': 's3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
            'Args': [
                's3://my-bucket/spark-driver-install.sh',
            ]
        }
   },
   ...other steps...
]
```

Which, as you've experienced, will fail on EMR 4.x if you just swap `command-runner.jar` for `script-runner.jar`, there.

Instead, make a bootstrap action to call the script, like:

```
BootstrapActions=[
    {
        'Name': 'Install My Spark Drivers',
        'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
            'Path': 's3://my-bucket/spark-driver-install.sh',
            'Args': []
        }
    }
]
```

The above example is expressed as [boto3 run_job_flow kwargs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow).  It's not immediately obvious to me how to accomplish the same thing in the web console, though.

Answer (score 0):

For executing a script you can use script-runner. I was also facing the same issue. My script had ^M characters which was causing this issue. Removing those worked.